# Label .NET software

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

I've always used BarTender from https://www.seagullscientific.com but we're using the older legacy version v10.1 automated for quite sometime now. Though the licensing is quite expensive, my current work place are not willing to upgrade to newer version and extend our printer count licensing.

We print to Zebra and Citizen printers with approximately 25 label printers with approximately 50 different type of labels over using 3 ERPs which are integrated using web services. Must support Code128 and EAN13.

I'm wondering, what do you consider to be the best label printing which integrates with .NET? Is it BarTender or alternative software?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you refer to software made in .NET or software with an API callable from a .NET program?

Comment: Sorry for not been clear. I'd prefer software with APIs callable from a .NET program.

Comment: Had you any luck find your software?